# How to run a loop on the elements in workspace?

Tags: r

```
> ls()
 [1] "A"          "anorex.1"   "anorexia"   "B"          "byMonth"    "C"          "clotting"  
 [8] "counts"     "d"          "D"          "d.AD"       "DelayByDay" "delayed"    "glm.D93"   
[15] "glmout"     "groups"     "h"          "housing"    "madeup"     "notdelayed" "outcome"   
[22] "q19"        "q22.1"      "q23"        "q23.1"      "q25"        "q25.1"      "q26"       
[29] "q26.2"      "speed"      "tmp"        "treatment"  "tt"         "w"          "wnd"       
[36] "x"          "y"          "z"
```

What I am thinking is lets say I want to know the class of all the objects in my workspace, and thought would like to write a loop, something to the effect of:

```
for(x in 1:38) print(class(ls(1)[x]))
```

But this gives me the character as the class for each object (which if i am not wrong is the class of the name of each object.)

I was trying to find out something about the objects in the workspace, class, length, or dim.  Could the for loop accomplish this, does one of apply functions also do this.
thx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your loop only uses a character name, so R thinks it's just a character vector.  You need to get the object itself.  You can use `mget()` to get multiple objects in a given environment, in a list, from a character vector.  That means we can pass it `ls()`. Then we can run through that list and get the class.

```
lapply(mget(ls()), class)
```

I use `lapply()` because it is entirely possible that some objects have more than one class.

If you want to know other attributes/information about the object, write a function.

```
f <- function(x) list(dim = dim(x), class = class(x))
lapply(mget(ls()), f)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `get()` for this. Like:

```
for (i in ls()) {
  print(get(i))
}
```